# Is there any way to download Adobe flash?

Tags: flash, downloads

I am trying to use Flash for habbo.com. I cannot get it to download. Is it even possible? Any recommendations or tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

Comment: @pomsky: Yeah, apparently it's a duplicate by nature. The problem is that (AFAIK) there is no good up-to-date question/answer here, but they are all full of historical noise which is irrelevant today.

Answer (score 2):

The package `flashplugin-installer` should do what you want. Just bear in mind that it uses Adobe's own plugin and you implicitly agree to their license. (I think that's [this](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/legal/licenses-terms/pdf/Flash_Player_27_0.pdf) and [this](https://www.adobe.com/legal/terms.html).) There have also been a lot of [security problems](http://bgr.com/2015/10/15/adobe-flash-player-security-vulnerability-warning/) with Flash over the years.

You'd install it with the usual `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer`.